# LoginViewController -> OtherviewController Two-way Segue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am new to iOS development and XCode and am trying to figure out how to implement the following logic:

1) User starts app - user is directed to the LoginViewController that has a login form

2) Upon successful user login - go to the next view controller - let's call it LoginViewController

How do I programatically do that in the action logic for the login button in the view of LoginViewController e.g.

```
@IBAction func loginButtonPressed(button: UIButton) {
    //do login logic

    //what to put here to segue to OtherViewController
}
```

And once the user is in OtherViewController, it is possible their auth token will expire. If that happens I would need to segue back to LoginViewController. I come from an Android background where you would use Intents to make something like this happen - what is the equivalent in iOS?

An answer in Swift is preferred since I am more familiar with that, but I am decent at deciphering Objective C code as well.

As a side note- should I be controlling segues in code like this or should I be using storyboards? I tried creating segues in the storyboard but I do not understand how to hook those up to application code.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("name2", sender: self)
```

As an example:

```
@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("newView", sender: self)
    }
```

Here i created a modal segue from viewController1 to ViewController2 in the storyboard.  I did this by control-click on the yellow ViewController icon at the top of the view and drag the blue line to the second view.  Then release.  in the popup menu select modal segue.  Then in the utilities panel on the right - after highlighting the segue in the storyboard, click on the attributes inspector and give the identifier a name.  Then paste that name in the code example where I have "newView".

Comment: Does this mean I need to create a segue in the storyboard? And if so, what type of segue, the ones that seem to make sense would be `show` or `showDetail`

Comment: Yes, that is the best way. You can create a modal segue. Then give it an identifier and place it in the code I gave you.  let me know if you nee me to link to, or paste a screen shot.

Comment: I thought modal segue's were for putting up modal windows? Is there a resource somewhere that explains what all these different segue types do and what they should be used for?

Comment: It's a way to transition to another view controller.  As an alternative option you can create two UIViews in one ViewControlle and then after successful login hide one and show the other.  Slightly more complicated but works well.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can  init you next controller from storyboard:

```
UIStoryboard * storyboard = self.storyboard;

OtherViewController * otherVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @ "xxx * Name Desire"];
```

If you use navigation controller:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController: otherVC animated: YES];
```

Else:

```
[self presentViewController:otherVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```